# How To Convert String To Runnable Code In Java

Tags: java, runnable

I Have Java code stored as a string in a database. For example:

`String x = "System.out.println(\"X\")";`

I need to convert it into `java.lang.Runnable` to run it in task executor service. How Can I create it ?

```
private Runnable StringToRunnable(String task){
Runnable runnable = null;

return runnable;
}
```

Comment: This is an extremely bad idea on a security and implementation level.  Even to the extent this is possible -- which will be fairly difficult -- I can't recommend strongly enough that you *not do this.*

Comment: @SDJ I will see

Comment: @LouisWasserman but how can I store tasks to run it after restart server ?

Comment: @LouisWasserman can you recommend any idea ?

Comment: Lots of ways, but a simple one would be that you have a list of possible things to do, and you just store the name of one.  Store the string "printX", and somewhere in your program, have `if (stringFromDatabase.equals("printX")) { System.out.println("X"); }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Janino](https://janino-compiler.github.io/janino/) is a popular choice for an on-demand-compiler. It's being used by many open source projects.

The usage is straight forward. The code

```java
import org.codehaus.janino.ScriptEvaluator;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String x = "System.out.println(\"X\");"; //<-- dont forget the ; in the string here
        ScriptEvaluator se = new ScriptEvaluator();  
        se.cook(x);
        se.evaluate(new Object[0]);    
    }
}
```

prints `x`.

As others have already pointed out, loading code from the database and executing it might be a bit risky.

Answer (score 0):

I Created This Method

```
    private void getMethod(String fromClass, String fromMethod) {
    Class<?> aClass;
    try {
        aClass = Class.forName(fromClass);
        Method method = aClass.getMethod(fromMethod);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(aClass.newInstance());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and called it by

```
        Runnable task = () -> getMethod(fromClass, fromMethod);
```

and i put className and method Name in database by :

> this.getClass().getCanonicalName()   and string method name